# The responsiveness of my form fields doesn't work correctly

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

I am working on my first website and I encountered a problem with the responsiveness of the fields in my search form. I use Wordpress theme and plug-ins and I am overriding their styles with my own.

The field groups for "Price"and "Build-Up Area" don't behave as expected when I change the size of the browser window. I created media queries for every browser size which breaks the structure, but it seems that I need about 10 separate queries, even more, which I consider as inappropriate.

(e.g. I have a query for max-width 780px and then it appears that I have to create another one for max-width 767px, because for that browser size the structure is broken again) .

I have red the original CSS code of the theme/plug-in, but I can't understand where the problem comes from. 
What am I doing wrong? 
Thank you in advance!
[**my website**](http://zdravkapaneva.eu/wp/?page_id=343)

Answer (score 0):

Dont write css as per window size. Set the width in % for all screensize. For mobile, show the input field as one by one width as 100%.

Comment: Thank you, Selvakumar! Maybe I don't understand you correctly, but:

Comment: Thank you, Selvakumar! Maybe I can't understand you correctly. All the fields are with width in percentages, I haven't used pixels as a unit for any of them. If I follow your advice to show the input field as one by one width as 100%, on the row with the fileds for min/max built-in area I would have two fields, each of them with width: 100%, so the design breaks again. The situation is same with the price row, where are  situated 3 separate fields.Excuse me if my questions are amateur! :)